# Java Library system, Checking In & Out

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, append, checkout

We're making a library system that reads from a file to check books in, out, list them all, and show availability. I'm having trouble in the Main file with checkin and checkout. The checkin is done through the isbn. It finds the book in the system and appends the checkout date at the end (MM/DD/YYYY). There's not a way to add books. The check in and out are already called from mainGUI so I don't have to do that part, but how do I make the checkout method add the checkoutdate to the book in the list and make it remove the checkoutdate for the checkin method? (they're empty here)

```
package swe;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import swe.BookGUI.LoginGUI;


public class Main {

ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>(); // Initialize the list of books
BookFileHandler reader;

/*
/ Initial actions to be taken by the program upon start.
*/ 
public void init() throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    populateBookList();
}
/*
/ Used to populate the bookList with books from the book file. 
*/
private void populateBookList() throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    reader = new BookFileHandler(new File("Books.txt"));
    Book tmp;
    tmp = reader.getNextBook();
    while(tmp != null)
    {
        bookList.add(tmp);
        tmp = reader.getNextBook();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoginGUI login = new LoginGUI();
}

public ArrayList<Book> getBookList()
{
    return bookList;
}

public void checkIn(String ISBN)
{ String title, author, checkoutDate; 
  int isbn;

}

public void checkIn(Book b)
{

}

public void checkOut(String ISBN)
{

}

public void checkOut(Book b)
{

}

public Book findByAuthor(String author)
{
    for(Book x : bookList)
        if(x.getAuthor().equalsIgnoreCase(author))
            return x;
    return null;
}

public Book findByTitle(String title)
{
    for(Book x : bookList)
        if(x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(title))
            return x;
    return null;
}

public Book findByISBN(String ISBN)
{
    for(Book x : bookList)
        if(x.getIsbn().equalsIgnoreCase(ISBN))
            return x;
    return null;
}

public void showBookInfo(Book b)
{
    if(b != null)
    {
        String info = "ISBN: " + b.getIsbn() + "\nTitle: " + b.getName() + "\nAuthor: " + b.getAuthor() + "\nCheckout date (null if not checked out): " + b.getCheckoutDate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, info,"Book info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public void listBooks()
{
    String list = "";
    for(Book b : bookList)
    {
        list += "ISBN: " + b.getIsbn() + "\nTitle: " + b.getName() + "\nAuthor: " + b.getAuthor() + "\nCheckout date (null if not checked out): " + b.getCheckoutDate();
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list ,"Book list", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}

public void sortByAuthor()
{
    ArrayList<Book> tmp = new ArrayList<Book>();
    for(Book b : bookList)
    {
        if(!tmp.isEmpty())
        {
            for(int x =0; x < tmp.size(); x++)
            {
                if(b.getAuthor().compareTo(tmp.get(x).getAuthor()) > 0)
                {
                    if(tmp.get(x+1) == null)
                    {
                        tmp.add(b);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(b.getAuthor().compareTo(tmp.get(x+1).getAuthor()) < 0)
                        {
                            tmp.add(x, b);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: For check out, it should add on the checkout date to the book being taken by calling the current date from the system. Book entries in the file are written line by line like this `(358401214,, Dr. Seuss,, The 500 Hats Of Bartholomew Cubbins,, 05-01-2014,, <>)` For check in, it should just remove that checkout date from the book.

Comment: Thank you. How should I go about adding on the checkout date to books when they're being taken out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your books are mapped by `ISBN` so to remove the checkout date you can loop over each of them, and remove the date when the ISBN match :

```
public void checkIn(String ISBN)
    for(Book b : booklist)
    {
       if(b.getIsbn().equals(ISBN))
       {
           b.setCheckoutDate("");
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

Or with Java 8 you could replace the for-each loop with

```
booklist.stream()
    .filter(book -> book.getIsbn().equals(ISBN))
    .forEach(book -> book.setCheckoutDate(""));
```

if you prefer.

**Edit**

As per your comment, if you want to add to add the checkout date when the book is taken out, then the same algorithm apply. Loop over each books then when the ISBN match, you set the checkout date to the current date.